# Uploaded image name need to change

Tags: php, html

After Uploading image it shows date in the name of image in uploadfolder.Instead

need to show ward number which is posted in $ward.The commentline was i changed

but its not working.please help me.

```
$image_name = "img_"."_".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".png";

// $image_name = "img_"."_".$ward.".png";
```

Comment: What issue you are getting?

Comment: Upload not working.is there any error with my code.

Comment: What is the `output` you are getting when you `echo $image_name = "img_"."_".$ward.".png";`

Comment: instead of ward it is ok to take random number then how is the code will be?please help me

Comment: are you getting any error? post the output of `echo $image_name = "img_"."_".$ward.".png";`

Comment: when i print it shows img-wardnum saved successfully.bt in upload folder not there

Comment: Can you show your whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```
$ward = $_POST['ward'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];//name of your input file name
$uploads_dir = "Your Upload idrectory path";
$image_name = "img__".$ward.".png";

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$image_name");
```

Comment: sir its working.thank u.

Comment: please mark this as accepted and vote up -thanks

Answer (score 0):

The image name should have the ward name so that the saved file will have the same name. U need to get the ward name in some variable say $ward which is posted from the form, then add this $ward as an extension to the image name.

```
$ward = $_POST['ward'];
$uploads_dir = "";//path where the image needs to be stored in ur computer
$image_name = "img_".$ward.".png";
```

Try this code snippet in the original code and the extension of the image will be changed